# Using Sublime Text 2 with Python 3 under Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, plugins, sublimetext2

I am developing a plugin for sublime text 2 using python. As default, sublime text 2 uses python 2, but I'd like to switch to python 3. There are some hints on how to do that (also here on stackoverflow), but none of them seem to work for me. Maybe because I am using windows and there should be something different here?

My `Python.sublime-build` file looks as follows:

```
{
  "path" : "C:/Python34",
  "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

It is not working like that. When I use the following code in my plugin:

```
print('python version: ' + sys.version)
```

I get as a result

```
python version: 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 18:02:59) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Now what do I need to change? In the line with `cmd`, should it be `python3` instead of `python`? Or `python.exe`? I Also put the path to my python3 into the windows PATH environment variable (and not the one for python2), but I still get the output with `python 2.6.5`.

Any more ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing [plugins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) with [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html). Build systems (defined in `.sublime-build` files) are for running code through an external program, like a Python or Ruby interpreter, a Java or C++ compiler, `make`, or really any arbitrary program that takes input and gives output.

A Sublime plugin is a program written in Python that is executed by Sublime's *internal* Python interpreter, and generally makes use of the [API](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html) to perform actions within Sublime, such as code completion, linting, interacting with version control systems like Git, etc. Sublime Text 2 uses Python 2.6.5 internally, while ST3 uses Python 3.3.3.

If you are wanting to write a plugin, I **strongly** advise you to use ST3. It is quite stable (I have been using it almost exclusively for well over a year now), has many feature improvements over ST2, and uses Python 3 as its scripting language. The API is now completely thread-safe, leading to much better performance when you have many plugins running simultaneously, where a crash in one won't necessarily bring the whole system down. There is *no* development or bug-fixing work being done on ST2 (in fact, Sublime's author Jon Skinner has said that he is in the planning stages for ST4 now), while ST3 is currently being developed quite rapidly, with 17 new builds having been released since the end of January. Major new features have been released, including a tooltip API with mini-HTML formatting, a new language syntax definition format, improved error messages all around, major changes in build systems, and a bunch of tweaks all over the place.

Comment: That sounds great - so I am wondering why sublime text 3 is still in beta if what you said is true ...

Comment: @MathiasBader ST3 is still undergoing active development, so a "final" version hasn't been released yet. There are two versions - the [public beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), which anyone can use, and the [dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev), which only registered users can use. The dev builds are iterative, and can be less stable as new features are introduced along with the inevitable bugs. Public beta builds are released less frequently, usually at a point where things are pretty stable.

Comment: Basically, the term "beta" is meaningless - ST3 is just as stable as ST2, if not more stable than it. As far as any software is "production-ready", ST3 probably is. It's much preferable than using an ancient version of ST2 that was last updated in July of 2013. Nearly all new plugins being released on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) are ST3-specific, unless they don't use too many API features and so are compatible with ST2. Older plugins are primarily only seeing development in the ST3 branches, as it can be rather difficult to maintain two codebases.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Makes absolutely sense - I just don't understand the way this is communicated by the sublime text team. Anyone who doesn't have more information goes to the website and thinks: 'He, let's better download st2 since st3 is still beta'. Especially since the download page says clearly: 'The current version of Sublime Text 2 is 2.0.2. Sublime Text 3 is currently in beta ...' Not the best communication in my opinion ...